# Generate MVT with POSTGIS and feature tolerance

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geodjango

I have a database which has three geometry tables 'tbl_point, tbl_line, tbl_polygon' with millions of features.

Each table has two geometry columns named geom & m_geom for geometries and multi-geometries respectively.

I am generating MVT using POSTGIS with following query.

```
WITH 
   bounds AS (SELECT ST_Segmentize(ST_MakeEnvelope(8247861.100083642, 3546678.1124321707, 
      8252753.069893893, 3551570.082242422, 3857),1222.9924525627866) AS geom, 
      ST_Segmentize(ST_MakeEnvelope(8247861.100083642, 3546678.1124321707, 8252753.069893893, 
                    3551570.082242422, 3857),1222.9924525627866)::box2d AS b2d
     ), 
  f_300 AS (SELECT ST_Simplify(ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.geom, 3857), bounds.b2d, 4096, 128, true), 20) 
            AS geom, t.id FROM tbl_line t, bounds 
            WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 4326)) 
            AND t.shp_id = 300 AND t.deleted = FALSE
            UNION
            SELECT ST_Simplify(ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.m_geom, 3857), bounds.b2d, 4096, 128, true), 20) 
            AS geom, t.id FROM tbl_line t, bounds
            WHERE ST_Intersects(t.m_geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 4326)) 
            AND t.shp_id = 300 AND t.deleted = FALSE
           ), 
 f_299 AS (
           ......
           AS geom, t.id FROM tbl_point t, bounds 
           ......
          ), 
f_307 AS ( ......
           AS geom, t.id FROM tbl_polygon t, bounds 
           ......
         )
                 
SELECT ST_AsMVT(f_300.*, '300') FROM f_300
UNION 
SELECT ST_AsMVT(f_299.*, '299') FROM f_299
UNION 
SELECT ST_AsMVT(f_307.*, '307') FROM f_307
```

The query exludes small polygon using ST_Simplify tolerance. But for points and lines its returning all the features which becomes very congested while displaying.

Is there any way to show only some of the features or group features or cluster features.

Also, any recommendation on improving the query is highly appericiated.

[image: Data Congestion]

Comment: Are you trying to simplify your points and lines for different zoom levels ?

Comment: If so , look into tippecanoe- https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe.  This will make things much easier for rendering what you need at different zoom levels

Comment: @the_darkside I need dynamic tiling and wanted to exclude some features at different zoom levels.

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe/issues/741

Comment: Similar to what i was looking for. Can it be done using ST_ASMVT as my data changes every minute